# React Invalid Hook Call Error with useState In Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I followed the invalid hook warning found [here](https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call) to no avail. Is there some error I'm overlooking in my code. When I use the command npm ls react-dom I get: "react-dom@17.0.2". What is wrong in my code? I thought you could use the useState hook in a functional component like I did below

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function Navbar()
{
  const [childFontSize, setChildFontSize] = useState("5vh"); 

  return(
    <div id={"navbarContainer"}> 
      <span className={"font"}>XYZ</span>
      <span className={"font"} style={{fontSize: childFontSize}}>XYZ</span>
      <span className={"font"} style={{fontSize: childFontSize}}>XYZ</span>
      <span className={"font"} style={{fontSize: childFontSize}}>XYZ</span>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(Navbar(), document.getElementById("navbar"));
```

Comment: Is this React for the browser or React Native? ReactDOM is only used for browsers, but you've added the `react-native` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```js
ReactDOM.render(Navbar(), document.getElementById("navbar"));
```

Functional components should never be called as functions, they need to be either called with JSX or React.createElement.

```
ReactDOM.render(<Navbar />, document.getElementById("navbar"));
```

or (don't do this) you can call `React.createElement` (which is what the JSX gets transpiled into): https://reactgo.com/react-createelement-example/

```js
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Navbar, null, null), document.getElementById("navbar"));
```

```js
// not on StackOverflow
// import {useState} from 'react';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import './index.css';

const useState = React.useState;

function Navbar()
{
  const [childFontSize, setChildFontSize] = useState("5vh"); 

  return(
    <div id={"navbarContainer"}> 
      <span className={"font"}>XYZ</span>
      <span className={"font"} style={{fontSize: childFontSize}}>XYZ</span>
      <span className={"font"} style={{fontSize: childFontSize}}>XYZ</span>
      <span className={"font"} style={{fontSize: childFontSize}}>XYZ</span>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Navbar />, document.getElementById("navbar"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="navbar"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The <> solution around the functional component's name workd!